# Controlled components and props WITHOUT componentWillReceiveProps()

Tags: reactjs

The current recommendation is to no longer use the componentWillReceiveProps() method. At the same time the recommendation is to use controlled components instead of uncontrolled components when using a form.

However, to me those two concepts seem to be at odds when receiving the initial form values from props.

Previously, I have created my class as follows:

```
class UserDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            first_name: this.props.user.first_name,
            last_name: this.props.user.last_name
        }
    }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
          //update state with new props
   }


    async handleSave(){
         //send data to the api from the state
    }

    handleChange(event){
         //sets state based on changes to form field
    }

    render(){
          return (
              <div>
                   <Input id="first_name" value={this.state.first_name} handleChange={(evt)=>{this.handleChange(evt)}} />
                   <Input id="last_name" value={this.state.last_name} handleChange={(evt)=>{this.handleChange(evt)}} />
                   <button onClick={()=>this.handleSave()}>Save Changes</button>
              </div>
          )

    }
```

}

export default UserDetails;

So what is the recommended way now to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

A controlled component in my view means it is controlled by someother component. So we send props to child component and use them in child. You need not have separate state for this component. You can always use props in your render method (unless you have some calculations to be done based on props which still can be handled without using state.)

If we are using props we can skip writing componentwillreceiveprops method.
In case you want to handle forms, why not use state lifting and call parent component method?
This way your current component will be controlled and also it can be reused in any other places of your application. (Because, we will be just using whatever the parent component gives and child just consumes the props and invokes parent methods when needed)

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble wrapping my head around state lifting. I have updated my above code to something more specific. Are you suggesting that the parent should handle state for all of its children? Are you suggesting that the parent should have handleChange and handleSave functions for each of its children components? To me it does not make sense to lift the state and functions to the parent component, because that adds much more overhead to the parent. The parent then ends up looking bloated. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

> At the same time the recommendation is to use controlled components
>   instead of uncontrolled components when using a form

This is partially correct. You can either use:

1. A controlled component.
2. A fully uncontrolled component with a key.

Also, the code that you added is an `anti-pattern` because you are erasing the `state` based on `props`. You also have a `handleChange` which will `setState` based on the input value of the user. So the problem here is that there is two sources of truth instead of one to set the `state`.

As per your use case, you want to have an initial value from `props`, then you can use a fully uncontrolled component with a key to achieve this.

What this means is our component could still accept a `prop` for the initial value, but it would ignore subsequent changes to that `prop`.

You can read about this pattern and anti-pattern [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)

Comment: Using key like this definitely seems useful. However, I was always under the assumption that a controlled form component means that whenever you change the value of the field it updates state. Am I misunderstanding what a controlled component is?

Comment: That is correct, however your field say `input` may be controlled by the `state` of the same component or some other component which is in the most case parent component.

I think you are confused between when to use component own's state vs using parent's state to control the field in child.

You should re-read the article that I gave in my answer, it has all the cases covered with working demos. It takes a while to get all of it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is using `componentDidUpdate` and checking if the property `user` changed.

Here is the code - added bonus refactor with Hooks for fun ;)

**using componentDidUpdate**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

/// WITHOUT HOOKS

class UserDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      first_name: this.props.user.first_name,
      last_name: this.props.user.last_name
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.props.user
      });
    }
  }

  async handleSave() {
    //send data to the api from the state
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChange = field => e => {
    this.setState({
      [field]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("rendering");
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{`User: ${this.state.first_name}`}</label>
        <br />
        <input
          id="first_name"
          value={this.state.first_name}
          onChange={this.handleChange("first_name")}
        />
        <input
          id="last_name"
          value={this.state.last_name}
          onChange={this.handleChange("last_name")}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.handleSave()}>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    c: 0,
    user: {
      first_name: "asd",
      last_name: "das"
    }
  };
  handleChangeUser = () => {
    const { c } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      c: 1 + c,
      user: {
        first_name: `asd_${c}`,
        last_name: `asd_${c}`
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserDetails user={this.state.user} />
        <button onClick={this.handleChangeUser}>change user</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**using useEffect hook**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
// WITH HOOKS

function UserDetailsWithHooks(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    ...props.user
  });

  const handleChange = field => e => {
    setUser({ ...user, [field]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log(user);
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setUser(props.user);
    },
    [props.user]
  );

  console.log("rendering");
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{`User: ${user.first_name}`}</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="first_name"
        value={user.first_name}
        onChange={handleChange("first_name")}
      />
      <input
        id="last_name"
        value={user.last_name}
        onChange={handleChange("last_name")}
      />
      <button onClick={() => handleSave()}>Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const AppHooks = () => {
  const [c, setC] = useState(0);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    first_name: "asd",
    last_name: "das"
  });

  const handleChangeUser = () => {
    const newC = 1 + c;
    setC(newC);
    setUser({
      first_name: `asd_${newC}`,
      last_name: `asd_${newC}`
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserDetailsWithHooks user={user} />
      <button onClick={handleChangeUser}>change user</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<AppHooks />, rootElement);
```